# Why some methods we can apply to an object and define it in a variable, but for some we cant?

Tags: python, variables, methods

if we have a file, we can read the lines and store it in a variable. such as:

```
with open('test.py', 'r') as file:
    f = file.readlines()
```

however, for some methods we **can't** add it to an object (sort it) and store in a variable:

```
cars = ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']
y = cars.sort()
print(y)
```

And we should do:

```
cars = ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']
cars.sort()
print(cars)
```

Why?
Yeah, this might be a banal question, however, there's no learning without banal questions.

Comment: `.readlines()` returns a value, but`.sort()` doesn't.  Simple as that.  (Well, it does, but it's always None.)

Comment: The purpose of `.sort()` is to sort the list in-place.  You can use `sorted()` in your example.

Comment: Lol, I read your first message, started thinking about None, and missed the rest of the sentence. 
I've been thinking like, what's the difference between None and the thing when a lot of symbols are in brackets like 0x<239233294944> ? . blah, blah, blah
  
Sure, I got. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` modifies the `list` instance in-place, so it does not return anything. It is a convention for mutating methods to return nothing (i.e. `None`).

You can use `y = sorted(cars)` to create a sorted *copy* of the `cars` list.

Comment: Additionally, some functions support both mutation and non-mutation with a flag. I think `pandas.DataFrame().sort()` has a inplace flag to decide whether it sorts inplace or not and defaults to `False`.